# SplFileObject not reading CSV properly

Tags: php, csv, splfileobject

So I have to read multiple CSV files, merge their headers(by removing duplicates) and put values in a final(merged) CSV file. I am trying to use `SplFileObject` for the first time. I started by reading  a file. Below are details

**file1.csv**

```
"A","B","C","D
1,2,3,4
```

**merge.csv**

```
$file = new SplFileObject('file1.csv');
$file->setFlags(SplFileObject::READ_CSV);
foreach ($file as $row) {
    print_r($row);
}
```

It outputs:

```
Array
(
    [0] => A
    [1] => B
    [2] => C
    [3] => D
1,2,3,4
)
```

Why it did not make another array for the next row?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this, store your data in array and print it.

```
$file = new SplFileObject('file1.csv');
$file->setFlags(SplFileObject::READ_CSV);
foreach ($file as $row) {
   $new_array[] = $row;
}
print_r($new_array);
```

**OUTPUT**

```
Array
(
    [0] => A
    [1] => B
    [2] => C
    [3] => D
    [4] => 1
    [5] => 2
    [6] => 3
    [7] => 4
)
```

**OR**
try this,

```
$file = fopen('file1.csv', 'r');
while (($line = fgetcsv($file)) !== FALSE) {
  //$line is an array of the csv elements
  print_r($line);
}
fclose($file);
```

Comment: I need a an `SPLFileObject` based solution and yours one is not working. it prints same output.

Comment: Turns out it was issue in my CSV file. Thanks